# Expected log value of noncentral exponential distribution

Tags: mean, expected-value, integral

Suppose $X$ is non-central exponentially distributed with location $k$ and rate $\lambda$.  Then, what is $E(\log(X))$.

I know that for $k=0$, the answer is $-\log(\lambda) - \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.  What about when $k > 0$?

Comment: Have you tried integrating in Mathematica?

Comment: @Procrastinator: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried online, but the computation times out.  I unfortunately don't own Mathematica.

Comment: I assume $k > 0$ (when the density is written as $\lambda \exp\{-\lambda(x-k)\}$,) otherwise $x < 0$ with probability > 0, with dreadful consequences for $\mathbb{E}\log x$.

Comment: @jbowman is right.  I tried to integrate it like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log%28x%2Bm%29ke%5E%7B-kx%7D+dx+from+x%3D0+to+infinity

Comment: I got ${\mathbb E}[\log(X)]=e^{k\lambda}\Gamma(0,k\lambda)+\log(k)$. Mathematica is faster if you use the command `Assumptions` for specifying the  parameter space.

Comment: Given that these integrals have a closed form shouldn't we as mathematicians be able ot do the integration without the aid of Mathematica?

Comment: @MichaelChernick It always help and does not take too long to have a quick look on the outcome of Mathematica. Also, we know that this integral have a "closed form" thanks to Mathematica, otherwise how? This sounds a bit circular. The next step would be to check this integral by hand, depending on the goals of the OP.

Comment: Does the upper incomplete gamma function count as *closed form*? (To me, it does not.) This is just conveniently hiding an integral via notation.

Comment: @Procrastinator: Wow! Would you mind adding an answer?  I am also very interested in the command you used with Mathematica.

Comment: @cardinal:  You're right.  But, for my purpose Procrastinator's answer is perfect because I want to implement this in software and there are software libraries that evaluate the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: I tried to do this integral by hand, but wasn't able to.  I am also very interested in seeing such a solution.  (I remember seeing whuber solve some amazing integrals on other questions…)

Comment: @NeilG I guess my point is that maybe our increasing reliance on the computer is making us a little lazy by allowing a machine to do something we should be able to do ourselves. However, having said that when I was doing my PhD over 30 years ago I always got hung up with algebra mistakes that would take a long time to catch and correct and automated tools that do not err would have really come in handy back then.

Comment: @NeilG This is the Mathematica code `Integrate[Log[x + k]*\[Lambda]*Exp[-\[Lambda]*x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]},
  Assumptions -> k > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0]`. You can just copy it and paste it on a .nb file. I am not sure if the Wolfram Alpha allows for including restrictions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*The desired integral can be wrestled into submission by brute-force manipulations; here, we instead try to give an alternative derivation with a slightly more probabilistic flavor.*

Let $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(k,\lambda)$ be a noncentral exponential random variable with location parameter $k > 0$ and rate parameter $\lambda$. Then $X = Z + k$ where $Z \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$.

Note that $\log(X/k) \geq 0$ and so, using a [standard fact for computing the expectation of nonnegative random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26020/geometric-distribution-without-replacement/26033#26033),
$$
\newcommand{\e}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\rd}{\mathrm d}\renewcommand{\Pr}{\mathbb P}
\e \log(X/k) = \int_0^\infty \Pr(\log(X/k) > z)\,\rd z = \int_0^\infty \Pr(Z > k(e^z - 1)) \,\rd z \>.
$$
But, $\Pr(Z > k(e^z -1)) = \exp(-\lambda k(e^z - 1))$ on $z \geq 0$ since $Z \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ and so
$$
\e \log(X/k) = e^{\lambda k} \int_0^\infty \exp(-\lambda k e^z) \, \rd z = e^{\lambda k} \int_{\lambda k}^\infty t^{-1} e^{-t} \,\rd t \>,
$$
where the last equality follows from the substitution $t = \lambda k e^z$, noting that $\rd z = \rd t / t$.

The integral on the right-hand size of the last display is just $\Gamma(0,\lambda k)$ [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and so
$$
\e \log X = e^{\lambda k} \Gamma(0,\lambda k) + \log k \>,
$$
as confirmed by [@Procrastinator's Mathematica computation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30684/expected-log-value-of-noncentral-exponential-distribution#comment59130_30684) in the comments to the question.

**NB**: The equivalent notation [$\mathrm E_1(x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions) is also often used in place of $\Gamma(0,x)$.

Comment: +1 @Michael Chernick It seems like not everyone is lazy ;).

Comment: This is really great.  I just want to point out for anyone implementing this that many implementations of the incomplete gamma function restrict the first parameter to be strictly positive.  The identity $\Gamma(0, z) = -\operatorname{Ei}(-z)$ solves that minor problem.