# Variance of log($X_{\lambda}$) where $X_{\lambda}$ is a exponential function?

Tags: exponential-distribution

Let $X_{\lambda}$ has exponential density $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. Then what is the nature of Var log($X_{\lambda}$) w.r.t $\lambda$ i.e. is it increasing, decreasin, etc on $\lambda$.

My approach: Without going into calucaltion, I evaluate log($X_{\lambda}$) which then has a term of the form $-\lambda$ log($\lambda$) which I know is decreasing and hence the answer is decreasing which matches up with the correct answer. 
But when I want to explicitly evaluate the term of E$[X]$, I am running into problem because it's of the form $\lambda log(\lambda)\int_{0}^{\infty}- x dx$. This integral would give me $\infty$ and same problem occurs with E$[X^2]$. So can anyone help?

Comment: Since $\lambda$ is the inverse of the scale of the exponential, the negative of its log is a shift parameter for the density of $\log(X)$; it has no effect on the variance whatever.

Comment: @Gleb_b could you elaborate your comment, perhaps in a form of an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Without carrying out the variance derivation, I can say the following. If
$$X\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$$
then $Y=\log X$ is as follows
$$\begin{align}
\text{Pr}(Y\le y)&=\text{Pr}(\log X\le y)\\
&=\text{Pr}(X\le e^y)\\
&=1-e^{-\lambda e^{y}},\quad\quad\quad -\infty<y<\infty
\end{align}$$

We can check that this is a valid CDF if
$$F(-\infty)=0$$
and
$$F(\infty)=1$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dy}F(y)=f(y)\ge0,\quad\forall y$$

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30684/expected-log-value-of-noncentral-exponential-distribution) for a discussion of your problem in more detail.