# Is the ratio of two noncentral exponential distribution the logistic distribution?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, ratio, non-central

Is the ratio of two noncentral exponential distribution the logistic distribution? If yes, How to set the parameter of the logistic distribution using the parameters of noncentral exponential distribution?

Comment: Do you have a definition of "noncentral exponential"? Do you mean "noncentral chi-squared with 2df? If so, what values are you suggesting for the two noncentrality parameters?

Comment: e.g. Exp(m, lambda), where m is the location parameter, and lambda is the rate parameter.

Comment: That's not a definition, that's just setting up notation/parameters and a name. Is the density different from a noncentral chi-squared with 2df? If it is different from that, you need to link a definition for the density or the cdf or whatever. If not different, you need to answer my last question above.

Comment: It is definitely different from noncentral chi-squared with 2df. What's the relationship between exponential distribution and chi-squared distribution with 2 df? The density function for Exp(m, lambda) is lambda*exp(-lambda*(x-m)).

Comment: $\lambda e^{-\lambda(x-m)}$ is the density for a plain shifted-exponential. Where did you see that called "noncentral"?

Comment: What do you think it should call?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30684/expected-log-value-of-noncentral-exponential-distribution

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wrote what it's more usually called just above (shifted exponential). I'm debating about pointing out at that question that there's strong potential for confusion with a special case of the noncentral chi-square and the existence of a less ambiguous term.