# If MGF exists, does it imply that all $E(X^n)$ exist?

Tags: self-study, distributions, moment-generating-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Existence of the moment generating function and variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32706/existence-of-the-moment-generating-function-and-variance)

Given that there is an interval $-h < t < h$ where MGF exists, does it imply that the distribution's $E(X^n)$ will be defined for all $n$?

Comment: I don't think this is an *exact* duplicate; this one is about all the moments, not just the variance

Comment: @Peter: That's true, but there is no essential difference in this case and this is discussed in the answer there. There was no option to close as an *essentially* exact duplicate. :-)

Comment: OK, @Cardinal then I will add my close vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The moment generating function need not exist and a distribution does not necessarily have any finite moments but if the momnet generating function exists in an open interval then quoting from Wikipedia  '

Calculations of moments: The moment-generating function is so called because if it exists on an open interval around t = 0, then it is the exponential generating function of the moments of the probability distribution:

E(X$^n$)=d$^n$/dt$^n$ M$_x$(0)  where M$_x$(t) is the moment generating function of the random variable X

n should be nonnegative.

Comment: But note that the opposite is untrue:  A distribution may have all moments finite, but still the moment-generating function may not exist! An example is the lognormal distribution. This is the basis for an example of two different distributions having all moments equal: One of the distributions in the example is lognormal. This could not happen with a distribution havingn a mgf: it characterizes the distribution.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for the add on contribution in comments.