# Get Characteristic Function from MGF?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, moment-generating-function, characteristic-function

I've been calculating characteristic functions and MGF's and was wondering whether we can always get the characteristic function simply by substituting $it$ instead of $t$ in the resulting equation. For example the normal MGF is
$
\exp{(\mu t + \frac{\sigma^2 t^2}{2})}
$
but if we substitute $it$ into that we get $
\exp{(\mu it - \frac{\sigma^2 t^2}{2})}
$ which is the characteristic function.
Can we always do this if the MGF exists in a neighborhood of 0?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the link between these two functions, provided the MGF exists. This was discussed in another question in this site: [Link between moment-generating function and characteristic function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44201/link-between-moment-generating-function-and-characteristic-function)