# Can a moment generating function exist for some non-zero if the moments do not all exist?

Tags: moments, moment-generating-function

Is it possible for the following to happen:

Some moment of a distribution does not exist. Then can the mgf exist for any t not equal to zero?

Comment: See some examples [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32787/2970). But, in general, think about the case where $X$ is nonnegative almost surely with an *arbitrary* distribution and $t < 0$ (**Hint**: Monotonicity.).

Comment: I am sorry: I do not quite understand the answer. Thanks for the link. The question is if a moment does not exist, can the mgf exist for some non-zero t? The link does not cover this case, or does it? I am sorry again and thank you for your help.

Comment: I realize the comment by @Cardinal is cryptic, but doesn't the paragraph following "What does the mgf say about the moments?" in his reference fully address your question?

Comment: Thanks, got it! The proposition there proves it. THanks again to all!!