# Sufficient conditions for multivariate MGF to be finite in neighborhood of zero

Tags: probability, moment-generating-function, multivariate-distribution

In the one-dimensional case, we have the following fact: (see [Existence of the moment generating function and variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32706/existence-of-the-moment-generating-function-and-variance?newreg=33317bd203c8484e81e015f3613217e1) for proof)

**Proposition**: The mgf $m(t)$ is finite in an open interval $(t_n,t_p)$ containing the origin if and only if the tails of $F$ are exponentially bounded, i.e., $P(|X|>x)≤Ce^{−t_0x}$ for some $C>0$ and $t_0>0$.

Is there a similar fact for multivariate random variables? My problem is with proving the "$\leftarrow$" direction as $\{e^{t'X}>e^{t'x}\} \not\subset \{X>x\}$ for $t,X,x \in \mathbb{R}^m, m>1$.

Are there maybe other known sufficient conditions for the mgf to be finite in an neighborhood of zero?