# Upper Bound of MGF for a non-negative random variable with bounded variance

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, moment-generating-function

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable with finite variance. It is obvious that its MGF  $E[e^{-\lambda(X-E[X])}]$ exists for $\lambda > 0$.

How to prove that $E[e^{-\lambda(X-E[X])}] \le \exp(\lambda^2 E[X^2]/2)$ for $\lambda > 0$?

Comment: $E[e^{-\lambda(X - E[X])}]$ is not MGF:  $E[e^{\lambda X}]$ is.

Answer (score 4):

The inequality $e^{-u} \leq 1 - u + u^2 /2$ holds for any $u \geq 0$. Replacing $u$ by $\lambda X$ and taking the
expectation we get
$$
   \mathbb{E}[e^{-\lambda X}] \leqslant 1 - \lambda \,\mathbb{E}(X) + 
   \lambda^2\,\mathbb{E}(X^2) /2. 
$$
Now since $1 + v \leq e^v$ for any $v$, by choosing $v := - \lambda \,\mathbb{E}(X) + \lambda^2 \mathbb{E}(X^2)/2$
$$
 \mathbb{E}[e^{-\lambda X}]  \leq \exp\left \{-\lambda \,\mathbb{E}(X) + \lambda^2 \,\mathbb{E}(X^2)/2 \right\}
$$
which is the result in OP.

Comment: Great answer, which fixes my previous answer's hole nicely! (+1)

Comment: Short and sweet, very nice :) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof adapted from [John Duchi's lecture notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/extra-notes/hoeffding.pdf), but it's off by a factor of $2$ if you don't mind :
We will assume throughout that $X$ has an MGF defined on a neighborhood of $0$, such that all of its moments exist (as [finite variance is *not* sufficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32706/305654)).

Let $X'$ be an independent copy of $X$, i.e. $X'$ has the same distribution as $X$ while being independent of $X$. We have
$$E[e^{-\lambda(X-E[X])}] = E_X[e^{-\lambda(X-E_{X'}[X'])}] \le E_XE_{X'}[e^{-\lambda(X-X')}]  $$
Where we have applied Jensen's inequality to $e^{\lambda E_{X'}[X']}:= f(E_{X'}[X']) $.

Now for convenience let $Y:= X-X'$. The trick is to notice that $Y$ and $-Y$ are identically distributed, which implies that $Y$ and $S\cdot Y$ are identically distributed when $S$ is an independent [Rademacher random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution), i.e. when $S$ only takes value $+1$ and $-1$ with equal probability.

This implies that
$$\begin{align*}
E_Y[e^{-\lambda Y}] &= E_YE_S[e^{-\lambda S\cdot Y}] \\
&= E_Y[E_S[e^{-\lambda S\cdot Y}\mid Y]]\\
&= E_Y[\cosh(-\lambda Y)] =E_Y[\cosh(\lambda Y)]\end{align*}$$

Now assume that $Y$ is supported on some interval $[-a,a]$. By Taylor's theorem, we know that for all $Y(\omega)$, there exists $\xi\in (0,Y)\cup (Y,0)$ such that
$$\cosh(\lambda Y) = 1 + \frac{\lambda^2Y^2}{2} + \frac{\lambda^3Y^3}{6}\sinh(\lambda\xi(Y)) \le  1 + \frac{\lambda^2Y^2}{2} + \frac{\lambda^3Y^3}{6}\sinh(\lambda a)$$

Because $Y$ is symmetric, we have that $E[Y^3]=0$, hence taking expectation we find
$$E_Y[\cosh(\lambda Y)] \le 1 + \frac{\lambda^2}{2}E_Y[Y^2]\le \exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2}{2}E_Y[Y^2]\right) $$
Where we have used the well known $1 + x \leq e^{x} $. All that is left is to observe that $E_Y[Y^2] = E_Y[X^2 + (X')^2 - 2XX'] = 2E[X^2] - 2E[X]^2 $ and it follows that
$$E[e^{-\lambda(X-E[X])}] \le \exp\left(\lambda^2 (E[X])^2\right)$$

Which is the desired result up to a factor $2$.

---

Now in the general case where $Y$ is not compactly supported, you can construct a sequence
$$Y_n = (-n)\vee(Y\wedge n) \in [-n,n]$$
which is bounded and converges pointwise to $Y$. It then follows from Fatou's lemma that
$$\begin{align*}
E_Y[\cosh(\lambda Y)]&\le \lim\inf_n E_{Y_n}[\cosh(\lambda Y_n)] \\
&\le \lim\inf_n \exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2}{2}E_{Y_n}[Y_n^2]\right)\\
&\le\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2}{2}E_Y[Y^2]\right)\end{align*}.$$
From which the same conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is quite helpful!

Comment: The inequality $Y^3 \sinh(\lambda \xi) \leq Y^3 \sinh(\lambda a)$ does not seem so easy since $Y$ can be negative and $\xi$ depends on $Y$. Maybe a justification could help?

Comment: @Yves : that's because I picked $\xi$ between $0$ and $Y$, so $Y^3 \sinh(\lambda \xi) $ is always non-negative, and then the upper bound follows from the fact that $Y\le a$ almost surely and that $\sinh$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: When $Y$ is negative I get $-\sinh(\lambda a) \leq \sinh(\lambda \xi) \leq 0$ because $-a \leq \xi \leq 0$ and $\sinh(-\lambda a) = - \sin(\lambda a)$. But then by multiplying by $Y^3 \leq 0$ I get $0 \leq Y^3 \sinh(\lambda \xi) \leq   -Y^3 \sinh(\lambda a)$ which still puzzles me.

Comment: $-Y^3\sinh(\lambda a) = Y^3\sinh(-\lambda a) \le Y^3\sinh(\lambda a) $ so seems like there is no problem... Or am I missing something ?